# dt2w not working with newly compiled kernel

Tags: android

I recently tried compiling a kernel for Redmi Note 4g(dior) with dt2w feature.

After compiling I successfully got that option in kernel auditor but it is not working at all ie. whenever my device screen off nothing happens when i tap.

I tried compiling kernel from various sources but still same result. I used following patch file for the dt2w Please someone help me about what i am missing.

[link](https://github.com/haoyangw/android_kernel_xiaomi_dior-1/commit/f9408a31ba683a552b958c44850a892f129aa5f1) to the patch file